# Couldn't load PyQGIS in QGIS 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, ubuntu

This issue appears to be occurring with some frequency to folks in some shape or form. I upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, with loss of python functionality.

My QGIS version is 2.2 from the official repository (not ubuntugis).

I have anaconda installed as my main python release, and I also used anaconda to install sip, since I received that error message earlier on.

`conda install sip`

Which left me with version 4.15.5. After installing that, the sip dependency was no longer an issue, and now it is "just" the `pyQGIS` and `qgis.core` dependencies causing problems.

I tried switching to the nightly build, but to no avail--still no python support.

I am not sure where the qgis package should be located--it may be just a `pythonpath` issue, but it may be an API version issue with underlying dependencies, although `sip` does seem to be fine now.

Tips?

Comment: did you install the `qgis-python` package?

Comment: I did. I then switched gears, aiming to compile from source instead and am working through that process now.

Comment: Not sure what happened--attempted nightly builds, ubuntugis, then build from source (had dependency issues there, too, so never got past `cmake`), but update manager came up; it ran an extensive list, and I tried again with the official repo, and the python plugin is now working again.

Comment: Another thing I changed was to set my PATH variable to use the system python installation rather than the anaconda one.